# Crash when harmon.ie plugin is combined with AIP (Azure Information Protection) plugin

Tags: harmon.ie

The AIP plugin requires that the sender sets a data classification level (f.e. public, internal, confidential, strictly confidential) either at the moment of sending or at the moment of drafting the email.

If the user has not chosen the appropriate data-classification level, a pop-up reminds the sender that he/she should choose a data-classification level.

This pop-up conflicts with the harmon.ie pop-up to save the email on SharePoint after sending.

I can confirm there is no issue if:
* The sender has set the data-classification at the moment of drafting, OR
* The sender has chosen to not save emails automatically on SharePoint.

Nonetheless, is this an issue that can be solved by harmon.ie? F.e. by not hijacking the 'send email' window?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harmon.ie runs as a --.net addin-- so it can hardly crash Outlook.
In order to figure out this crash and check whether harmon.ie is directly involved we need to get the relevant crash dump.
In order to get a full dump of the crash you need to:

-Stop Outlook

-Install procdump utility from Microsoft (SysInternals) at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump

-Start Outlook

-Open a cmd command window, cd< directory_containing_procdump>

-Office 32bits:  procdump.exe -ma outlook -e  harmonie.dmp

-Office 64 bits:  procdump.exe -64 -ma outlook -e  harmonie.dmp

-Start Harmon.ie

-Reproduce the crash

-Upload the generated harmonie.dmp

---- Jean

Comment: Ok, 'crash' was not the correct description. Both Harmon.ie and AIP request user intervention right after sending the email, and both pop-up windows seem to be blocking eachother, resulting in an application that is blocked. Clicking in the pop-up windows a few times results in the message 'outlook seems to be not responding'.

Comment: Harmon.ie runs standard Outlook handler during send email operation (Outlook integration). Do you get harmon.ie dialog to save email upon sending the email? Please confirm whether you always get this dialog when sending an email. If yes, do you actually mean that once you get harmon.ie dialog, you do not get the AIP addin dialog/popup?